# Multilingual site with different requirements

Tags: php, google-translate

I know how to use Google API or Microsoft widget to make multilingual site, but this time i got different requirement from one of my client. The requirement is to find the location using user IP ,find language accordingly and then translate the web page into that language. I can find location and language as well, but how to translate webpage into that language? Can it be done in Microsoft widget or Google API? Need a tip to start.

Comment: This isn't that great of an idea. Just because people are accessing your site from a certain area, does not mean they speak, or read, in that language. At the very minimum, ask if they want to use that language before putting them into the full site. As for your question, did you try using either of those services?

Comment: Google's translate API will do this, but it's not free.